# AWS Lambda fails when using Playwright to navigate browser (Python)

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, playwright, langchain, playwright-python

I have created an LLM agent with tools using Langchain and Python. I build my Lambda with with AWS SAM with Docker. After building, I test the Docker image using `sam local invoke`, and the Lambda function executes as expected (on M1 Max chip), using Langchain's Playwright toolkit to navigate a headless, asynchronous chromium browser. After I deploy with SAM, I test the function in the AWS Lambda UI, but there is an issue with navigating the browser: `Target page, context or browser has been closed`. I do not experience this error when testing the lambda locally with `sam local invoke`.

Additionally, if the LLM agent does not use Playwright tools, then the Lambda executes as expected. This confirms that there is an issue using Playwright (via the Langchain package) within a deployed AWS Lambda function that is not experienced with local testing.

- Used image with Playwright in Dockerfile: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.21.0-focal. Expected Playwright browsers to properly configured. Browser still closes prematurely.
- Increased to 2048 MB. I hoped that more memory might solve the issue, but error still occurs.
- Followed [this](https://www.cloudtechsimplified.com/playwright-aws-lambda-python/#:%7E:text=Docker%20image%20for%20Playwright%20Python%20in%20AWS%20Lambda&text=You%20can%20build%20and%20push,Push%20Commands%22%20button%20at%20ECR.) guide for Dockerfile. I thought by adding aws-lambda-cpp build dependencies the issue might resolve, but it did not.
- Tried `--platform=linux/x86_64` and `--platform=linux/arm64` with Playwright image. `Architecture` set in Docker to correspond to choice. Error still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to Langchain's initialization of the async Playwright browser. The imported function `from langchain.tools.playwright.utils import create_async_playwright_browser` does not allow for arguments to be passed to `browser.chromium.launch()`. For the browser to function properly on AWS, `browser.chromium.launch(headless=True, args=["--disable-gpu", "--single-process"])`.

Here is the modification I made to get the Playwright browser to function properly in my AWS Lambda:

```py
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
from playwright.async_api import Browser as AsyncBrowser
from typing import List
from langchain.tools.playwright.utils import run_async

def create_async_playwright_browser(headless: bool = True, args: List[str] = None) -> AsyncBrowser:
    """
    Create an async playwright browser.

    Args:
        headless: Whether to run the browser in headless mode. Defaults to True.
        args: A list of arguments for the browser instance.

    Returns:
        AsyncBrowser: The playwright browser.
    """
    browser = run_async(async_playwright().start())
    if args:
        return run_async(browser.chromium.launch(headless=headless, args=args))
    else:
        return run_async(browser.chromium.launch(headless=headless))
```

Using this function to create the browser instead of the one found `langchain.tools.playwright.utils` results in the AWS Lambda functioning as desired